# How to setup PHP 8.1 as default version on Ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: php, upgrade, php-8.1

I have upgraded from PHP7.4 to PHP 8.1.It here when i use command line

```
$ php -v

PHP 8.1.12 (cli) (built: Oct 28 2022 17:39:37) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.12, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.12, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

[image]

but When i use built-in function `phpinfo()` to check PHP vertion.It still inform php 7.4.3.
What wrong in this situation.
Thanks so much !!

I have use command `sudo update-alternatives --config php` but it do not resolve this problem.I hope everyone here can help me !

Comment: which server you are using? probably it is set to use the old php version on that particular domain? You need to check apache / nginx configuration

Comment: Also, make sure, you restart the server